# Firefox OS display issue

Tags: html, screen-resolution, firefox-os

I am developing an app for GPS tracking on my new ZTE Open C device. Everything is working fine, but I have display issues:

- when I put this on the WebIDE simulator, the display is fine, and takes all the window,
- but when I send the app to my real device, the buttons and text are very small inside a big white area, and I have to zoom to see the text.

I have tested with other applications, and it is the same story everytime. So I don't think the problem comes from my app, but more likely from my device.

I got two ideas (but still don't know what to do):

- When I run the JavaScript commands `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight`, I get "450x320" for the simulator, but on my device I get "1258x800" in portrait mode and "800x435" in landscape mode. I think there is some point here.
- As I said, my device is a ZTE Open C running with Firefox OS B2G 2.1 (Aurora). And I am quite sure that the display was correct with the original version of Firefox OS I had with my device (1.1 if I'm correct).

I am quite new to HTML/Firefox OS and I've been stuck for several days.

Comment: Do you have `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` in your `<head>`?
`

Answer (score 0):

When working with firefox os if you are using

```
var intViewportWidth = window.innerWidth;
```

it does not seem to work well with 2.1, 2.2 or 2.5, the best suggested use for setting the view port in Firefox OS is to use the CSS element

```
<div style=" width: 100%; height: 100%"> </div>
```

or if you want to you can set it in the style sheet. In the things i have worked on i have found that no matter the device you are on setting it with the percent the view port is properly filled.